# Überbegriff für »Stadtverkehr«, »Überlandverkehr«, »Autobahnverkehr«?

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es einen Überbegriff für die Konzepte *Stadt-, Überland-* und *Autobahnverkehr*?

Kontextbeispiel:

> Parameter X ist unter anderem abhängig von *[Begriff, der die unterschiedlichen Einsatzgebiete, wie Stadt-, Überland und Autobahnverkehr, zusammenfasst]*.

Brainstorming:

- Fahrprofile
- Nutzungsprofile
- Einsatzgebiete
- ...

Ich suche nach einem Überbegriff, der die verschiedenen Einsatzbereiche eines PKW auf verschiedenen Ebenen des Straßennetzes beschreibt. Gibt es einen?

Der Begriff *Verkehrsart* wird lt. Wikipedia [im Bereich Verkehrsplanung abweichend definiert](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verkehrsart). Was natürlich nicht impliziert, dass ein anderer Fachbereich nicht etwas anderes darunter versteht. Der Kontext, für den ich mich interessiere, sind allgemeine, wissenschaftliche Studien/Publikationen im Bereich Mobilität, wie z.B. [Mobilität in Deutschland](http://www.mobilitaet-in-deutschland.de/).

Z.B., angenommen, man erstellt eine Grafik, die darstellt, wie groß der Anteil zurückgelegter Kilometer pro Person und Jahr für Stadt-, Überland- und Autobahnverkehr ist. Wie würde man die Abbildung überschreiben?

Comment: "Parameter X ist unter anderem abhängig von der *Art des Verkehrs*?"

Comment: @addy2012 Ich weiß nicht ob in dem Fall mit [_Verkehrsart_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verkehrsart) das richtige Konzept getroffen wird.

Comment: Spontan hätte ich "Art des Verkehrs" gesagt, aber wenn man bei dem Wikipedia-Artikel Vollständigkeit und Korrektheit annimmt, wäre dies ggf. missverständlich, da dort nicht zwischen "Stadt", "Land" etc. verglichen wird. Ob es "Verkehrs**typ**" besser macht, bezweifel ich.

Comment: PS: Du solltest in deiner Frage erwähnen, warum du Verkehrsart in Frage stellst. (Selbst, wenn du mit meiner Auffassung übereinstimmst.)

Comment: @Em1 Natürlich kann nicht davon ausgehen, dass der Wikipedia-Artikel vollständig und richtig ist. Und selbst wenn, könnte es sein, das in einem geringfügig abweichenden Fachbereich dem Begriff etwas völlig anderes zugeordnet würde. Ich bezweifle fast, dass es überhaupt einen speziellen Überbegriff dafür gibt.

Comment: Das müsste man natürlich klar stellen, um Verwechslung oder Missverständnis aufzuklären. Da ich mich dazu aber nicht auskenne, kann ich wenig dazu sagen. Aber zumindest kann ich das Problem nachvollziehen, bzw. ich würde die Wahl dieses Wortes auch in Frage stellen.

Comment: ich bin mir keiner verallgemeinerung bewusst, die nicht erklärt werden muss. man könnte vielleicht fahrgebiete sagen. dennoch muss es irgendwo erkärt werden, was gemeint ist. und wenn es eh erklärt wird, kann man auch das besser klingende verkehrsart nehmen.

Comment: Zur Abgrenzung: Ist eine Klassifizierung der Fahrtenlänge gemeint, also so etwas wie Kurz- Mittel- und Langstrecke? Oder der benutzte Straßentyp? In welche Kategorie soll eine ganz kurze Fahrt auf dem Dorf fallen? Da eine komplette Fahrt Abschnitte mehrerer Kategorien haben kann: Wird das abschnittsweise gezählt?

Comment: @guidot: Kurze Strecke im Dorf: Innerorts. Ich meine die klassische Unterscheidung ist die nach Straßenart, etwa Unfälle/km, Spritverbrauch, usw. Da spielt die Maximal- und Durchschnittsgeschwindigkeit rein, kreuzungsfreier Verkehr, Fußgängerüberwege, Straßenbahnen usw..

Comment: Im Wikipediaartikel zum Fahrzyklus ist die Rede von Verkehrs*bedingungen*.

Answer (score 9):

[Auf den Seiten des Umweltbundesamtes](http://www.umweltbundesamt.de/themen/verkehr-laerm/emissionsdaten) werden diese Begriffe unter *Verkehrssituationen* zusammengefasst (Hervorhebung hinzugefügt):

> Das Umweltbundesamt veröffentlicht in regelmäßigen Abständen das Handbuch für Emissionsfaktoren (HBEFA). Diese umfangreiche Datenbank zu den Emissionen von Luftschadstoffen des Straßenverkehrs stellt Emissionsfaktoren von Kraftfahrzeugen für die wichtigsten Luftschadstoffe und den Kraftstoffverbrauch zusammen. Die Daten sind nach zahlreichen technischen und verkehrlichen Parametern wie Fahrzeugart (Pkw, Lkw, Bus etc.), Abgasreinigung (geregelter, ungeregelter Katalysator etc.), Antriebsart (Otto, Diesel) sowie **Verkehrssituationen (Stadtverkehr, Landstraße, Autobahn etc.)** gegliedert.

Da Verkehrssituation ein ziemlich mehrdeutiger Begriff ist, kann man wohl nicht davon ausgehen, das ohne zusätzliche Nennung der Unterbegriffe klar ist, was konkret damit gemeint ist.

---

In den Unfallstatistiken wird in dem Zusammenhang generell von der *Ortslage* gesprochen.

Beispiel:

- https://www.destatis.de/DE/Themen/Gesellschaft-Umwelt/Verkehrsunfaelle/Tabellen/polizeilich-erfasste-unfaelle.html

Answer (score 6):

#### Streckentyp

Zur Beschreibung des Fahrverhaltens eines PKW und zur Bestimmung des Einflusses von Fahrten in bestimmten Bereichen des Straßennetzes findet man den Begriff *Streckentyp*, der als Überbegriff für die Unterscheidung zwischen *Stadt*, *Landstraßen* oder *Autobahnen* hergenommen wird.

Beispiele:

> - Diese Schwankung zeigt eine Abhängigkeit vom **Streckentyp**. So ergibt sich für den Stadtbereich eine Schwankung von 9,6 % bei einer Spannweite von 50 %, während auf den Bundesstraßen die Schwankungen nur bei 6,7 % bei einer Spannweite von 27 % des durchschnittlichen Verbrauchs auf dieser Streckenart liegt.<sup>[G. Baumann et al., Stuttgart](http://www.fkfs.de/uploads/publikationen/Baumann_VDI_SIMVEC_2010_Fahrereinfluss_Energieverbrauch.pdf)</sup>
> - Zum anderen wurden aus den Einzelverbrauchswerten der 28 Fahrzyklen [...] Trendlinine abgeleitet, die nach **Streckentyp** und Fahrweise klassifiziert sind. <sup>[C. Dorrer, Effizienzbestimmung von Fahrweisen...](https://books.google.de/books?id=sUrv1_ImvZsC&lpg=PA58&ots=hIUz6z2ghp&dq=streckentyp&pg=PA58#v=onepage&q=streckentyp&f=false)</sup>
> - Diese beiden Pkw-Typen haben zudem den Voreil, dass sie [...] und für einen bestimmten **Streckentyp** optimiert werden können.<sup>[O. Hurtig, Techno-ökoomischer Vergleich von Strom, SNG udn FFT-Diesel...](https://books.google.de/books?id=yldBAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA50&ots=I-UENfqcRG&dq=streckentyp%20fahrzyklus&pg=PA50#v=onepage&q=streckentyp%20fahrzyklus&f=false)</sup>

---

[image]
<sup>aus R. Brückmann et al. Forschungsvereinigung Automobiltechnik Nr. 151</sup>

Comment: Wenn ich das richtig verstanden habe bezieht sich _Streckentyp_ eher auf die Straßen an sich (und insb. ihren Ausbauzustand), als auf den dort vorkommenden Verkehr. Was nicht unbedingt unpassend sein muss.

Comment: Auch, denn es gibt den *Streckentyp* auch im Rennsport und zur Beschreibung des Kurvenreichtums an Teststrecken. So, wie ich es in der kurzen Zeit gesehen habe, wird es aber durchaus auch zur Unterscheidung der unterschiedlichen Verkehrssituationen im Straßenverkehr hergenommen. Vielleicht passt das auch zu Deiner Anwendung.

Answer (score 2):

Mit hinreichend Kontext und wenn ein Plural passt, könnte ***Verkehre*** Deine Kriterien erfüllen. In Fachsprachen ist es ja durchaus üblich, Plurale zu Wörtern zu bilden, die normalerweise Singulariatantum sind.

So könntest Du die als Beispiel genannte Grafik wie folgt überschreiben:

> Anteil der verschiedenen Verkehre am Gesamtverkehrsaufkommen

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke, *Verkehr* ist hier der grundsätzlich falsche Begriff - Er meint nämlich immer "du und die Anderen". Es scheint anhand deiner Beispiele allerdings nur um ein einziges spezielles Fahrzeug zu gehen, das betrachtet wird. Ein Fahrzeug alleine macht keinen *Verkehr*, sondern eine *Fahrt*. Die Tatsache, dass diese Fahrt vom *Verkehr* drumherum beeinflusst wird, und der Verkehr damit Auswirkungen auf die Fahrt hat, willst du anscheinend ausdrücken. Ich würde sowas wie

> Fahrten in unterschiedlichen Verkehrsprofilen

oder

> Fahrten in den verschiedenen Verkehrsklassen

als passend ansehen.

Möglicherweise geht auch

> Fahrten in unterschiedlichen Nutzungsprofilen